# java.io.BufferedReader.readLine() is nonblocking

Tags: java, swing, sockets, nonblocking, readline

I have a problem with readLine() in Java. I have a server and a client. From client I want to send a message to the server. The problem is that first, the client has to insert a text into a JTextField and when presses send then server to read the input from client, but server doesn't wait the input from client but instead reads null. But I read that readLine() is blocked until it has something to read, why it's not happening in this case?

Here I connect to the server and create the JFrame

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class StartingPoint {

private static PrintWriter out;
private static BufferedReader in;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                connectToServer();
                createAndShowGui();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public static void createAndShowGui() throws IOException {
    View frame = new View(out, in);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void connectToServer() throws IOException {
    String serverAddress = "127.0.0.1";

    int PORT = 8100;

    Socket clientSocket = null;
    out = null;
    in = null;

    try {
        clientSocket = new Socket(serverAddress, PORT);
        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not connect to the server \n" + e);
        System.exit(1);
    } finally {
        if (out != null)
            out.close();
        if (in != null)
            in.close();
        if (clientSocket != null)
            clientSocket.close();
    }
}
}
```

Here is JFrame implementation:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class View extends JFrame {

private JButton button;
private JTextField field;
private JPanel gui;

public View(final PrintWriter out, final BufferedReader in) throws IOException {

    button = new JButton("Send");
    field = new JTextField();

    gui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 10, 10));

    gui.add(button);
    gui.add(field);

    add(gui);

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            out.println(field.getText());

            try {
                System.out.println(in.readLine());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here is the server:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SimpleServer extends Thread {

public static final int PORT = 8100;
private static ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

private Socket clientSocket = null;

public void run() {
    String receive, answer;
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        receive = in.readLine();
        System.out.println("[server]" +  receive);
        answer = "hello " + receive;
        out.println(answer);
        out.flush();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("IO error \n" + e);
    } finally {
        try {
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Close socket error \n" + e);
        }

    }
}

public SimpleServer() throws IOException {

    while (true) {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

            new Thread(this).start();

        } finally {
            serverSocket.close();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    SimpleServer server = new SimpleServer();
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `connectToServer()` method opens a connection, creates streams and ... then closes them before returning.  So of course, the server sees the close straight away, and returns `null` on the first `readLine()` call.

---

I suspect that you may have copied the "close in a finally block" pattern without understanding what it means.  So I shall explain:

This is the normal pattern:

```
InputStream is = null;
try {
    is = new FileInputStream(someFile);
    // read the stream
} finally {
    if (is != null) {
        is.close();
    }
}
```

The purpose of the code above is to ensure that the InputStream is always closed.  Or more precisely, that it is always closed *before the try/finally exits*.

This is generally a good thing.  But if the purpose of your code is to open some streams that is going to be used after this bit of code completes, then closing the stream here is self defeating.

```
InputStream is = null;
try {
    is = new FileInputStream(someFile);
} finally {
    if (is != null) {
        is.close();
    }
}
// read the stream ... OOOPS!  We've already closed it!!
```

---

So to take this back to your original code, you need to move the try/finally/close stuff to the `run` method, something along these lines:

```
    public void run() {
        try {
            connectToServer();
            createAndShowGui();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (out != null)
                out.close();
            if (in != null)
                in.close();
            if (clientSocket != null)
                clientSocket.close();
        } 
    }
```

You should also catch and (probably) ignore `IOException` that might be thrown by each `close()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Javadoc for [`BufferedReader.readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29)
doesn't say anything like that:

> **Returns:**
>       A `String` containing the contents of the line, not including 
>       any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached

In your code you are opening a connection in connectToServer() and closing it, so server sees the end of stream